# Built in Camera in Dell C3422WE not recognized Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, dell, webcam, monitor, displayport

I have a Dell Monitor C3422WE with a built-in camera and microphone (for video calls).

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 with an Nvidia driver. The Nvidia card is connected to the monitor via DisplayPort. 
The sound works great, but when I pop up the camera, it is not recognized. Running `lsusb` or `lspci` doesn't even show a video cam.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the firmware update from https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=jhggh, perhaps this will fix the issue?

Jim